# Installing packages in SLES 12 SP3

Tags: package-management, sles, packages, zypper

I'm new to Suse and I have no idea how to do anything here. This is something I'm terribly new at and I can't figure out some basic stuff. First off, I'm used to Ubuntu. To install packages in Suse I'm using Zypper. It's fairly easy to do so and it's very similar to apt-get, but I feel like it's less powerful.

Many packages that I need are nowhere to be found. I keep finding some of the packages I need and it requires me to add a repository each time. Sometimes they work, but for some packages I simply can't find their repos.

A few to begin with:

- php7-imap
- php7-mcrypt
- php7-xml

I can't find repos for these no matter how hard I search. Also, some packages require other packages, which for some reason aren't included in the initial repo, despite being dependencies. For example: I need to install php7-dev (`php7-devel`), and it requires `pcre-devel`. I install `pcre-devel`, now it requires `libxml2-devel`. I can't install `libxml2-devel` because that one requires another package etc. Is there a way to automatically resolve dependencies with Zypper?

I need these packages to create a script which automatically installs a set of packages to setup a freshly installed system fast.

How to handle package installations in Suse?

Comment: Crossposting is frowned upon on here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394563/installing-packages-in-sles-12-sp3

Comment: @Lenniey Deleted it. Hopefully that makes you happy. I mean, such a minor "offence" is not even worth mentioning in my opinion. I didn't get any responses there, so I came for help here. Instead of micro-moderating these harmless "violations", why don't you take a minute to read the question and maybe even respond? I'm not doing this for mere fun, but it's a need for information and help. You are achieving nothing with a comment like yours except annoying me - you didn't save the StackExchange community with your tiny observation.

Comment: Mate, these are not my rules. I'd love to respond and help you, but I can't as I never experienced this issue with SLES (I'm using SLES 11 atm). Back to the topic: which repositories are set for zypper?